# Azure functio v3. .Net Core 3.1 The binding type(s) 'blobTrigger' are not registered

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have Azure function v3 .Net Core 3.1, just created from VS2019 template

Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions **v3.0.4**

When running function locally get the following error:

*The 'Function1' function is in error: The binding type(s) 'blobTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.*

With event hub binding the same error comes with 'eventhubTrigger'.
What is wrong?

function

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
        }
    }
```

csproj file

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 0306:**

Today, the issue is fixed in the new release of [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, version 3.0.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/3.0.5).

---

**Original answer:**

This is [an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/390) with latest version [Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/3.0.4), I can repro this error using the latest version.

please downgrade it to [3.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/3.0.3), and it can work well.